# Creating Performance Counters in Java

Tags: java, performancecounter

Does anyone know how can I create a new Performance Counter (perfmon tool) ***in Java***?

For example: a new performance counter for monitoring the number / duration of user actions.

I created such performance counters in C# and it was quite easy, however I couldn’t find anything helpful for creating it in Java…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java app performance counters viewed in Perfmon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358129/java-app-performance-counters-viewed-in-perfmon)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to develop your performance counter independently from the main code, you should look at aspect programming ([AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)).

You'll can plug your performance counter on the method(s) you want without modifying the main code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are expecting this tool to do but I would create some data structures to record these times and counts like

```
class UserActionStats {
   int count;
   long durationMS;
   long start = 0;

   public void startAction() {
       start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   }
   public void endAction() {
       durationMS += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
       count++;
   }
}
```

A collection for these could look like

```
private static final Map<String, UserActionStats> map = 
        new HashMap<String, UserActionStats>();

public static UserActionStats forUser(String userName) {
    synchronized(map) {
        UserActionStats uas = map.get(userName);
        if (uas == null)
            map.put(userName, uas = new UserActionStats());
        return uas;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your durationMS actually be incrementing: start - System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t think it exactly what I meant. I want to view my performance counter in perfmon tool. A simple measurement of duration or number will not be updated there and will not be stored in the perfmon logs

Answer (score 1):

Java does not immediately work with perfmon (but you should see DTrace under Solaris).

Please see this question for suggestions: [Java app performance counters viewed in Perfmon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358129/java-app-performance-counters-viewed-in-perfmon)